# Reposition bones without having to redo all poses?

Tags: rigify

I made a character and set up an animation with a number of poses.

I'm in process of tweaking the animation and I realized that a few bones, which I did not even use up till now (more specifically, the breast bones) are in the wrong places, or at least won't let me do what I want if they are left where they are.

I tried moving the bones in "edit mode", but that screws up the animation (the entire chest area is messed up), even if I repeat "parent with automatic weights" after editing. What's really confusing to me is that there are three different bones per side (ORG-breast.L, DEF-breast.L, and just breast.L, etc.) and I don't know which of these I can move.

I also tried to create a brand new bone and move it in the right place, then the  animation is not screwed up but the new bone has no effect on anything. Again, I redid parenting, I even tried to create a vertex group "custombone.L" in the character mesh (but I may have done that incorrectly). The bone shows up in the outliner and I can get a control for it to show up in "pose mode" but dragging or rotating it has no effect on the mesh.

What's the correct procedure here?

EDIT: I tried grabbing all visible bones in "edit mode" and moving them, and that seemed to work. But I'd still like to know how this is supposed to be done, and why there are three different bones per side.

Comment: Are you using rigify to generate a rig from a metarig, or some other automatic rig generator, such as an importer that includes an armature?

Comment: I used metarig to generate the initial rig.